# Using 2 wireless networks, 1 DHCP with internet, 1 using static IP without internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I have 2 networks at home, 1 is for our home wireless internet,etc which uses DHCP and my other one is for my home automation (PLC's, etc.). I am wanting to use another wireless router without internet for communicating to my automation servers and PLC's that use static IP's from the same laptop so I don't have to keep going to the server cabinet and hooking up seperate cables and such. Any suggestions as to how to do this easily and seamlessly. I admit I'm pretty decent with automation but not real strong on the IT side. Go figure.

Comment: If you don't need the two networks to talk to each other, you could literally set up two seperate wireless networks and then swap between them on your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need two networks at all?  Why not bridge the automation network to the home network, using a wireless ethernet bridge if necessary.  Now you have one network, and the automation components can use DHCP or static ip.  It also has the advantage of making the automation system available remotely.